# Executing a ViewModel function before setting variables in ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I have an issue with code order in a ItemsViewController.swift

When I run my code it starts the for items loop before my api returns the values for the items. This is done in the line: `self.viewModel/getItemsTwo...` Therefore it thinks that items is nil by the time the loop starts, so it errors with:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

How can I start the loop only after items has been filled by the api call/function call?

```
class ItemsViewController: UIViewController {
  private let viewModel : ItemsViewModel = ItemsViewModel()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    self.viewModel.getItemsTwo(self.viewModel.getCurrentUser())
    var items =  self.viewModel.items

    for item in items! {
        print(item)
    }
  }
...
```

The getItemsTwo function in the viewModel sets the viewModel.items variable when it is called

**EDIT 1**

ItemsViewModel.swift

```
...
var items : JSON?
...

func getItemsTwo(user: MYUser) {

    let user_id = user.getUserId()
    let url = String(format:"users/%@/items", user_id)
    self.get(url).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
        let dataExample = response.data
        var newdata = JSON(data: dataExample!)
        self.items = newdata
    }
}
...
```

**EDIT 2**

I am trying to do this:

just change it in the ViewController to:

```
var items = self.viewModel.getItemsTwo(self.viewModel.getCurrentUser())
```

and the ViewModel to:

```
func getItemsTwo(user: MYUser) -> JSON {

    let user_id = user.getUserId()
    let url = String(format:"users/%@/items", user_id)
    self.get(url).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
        let dataExample = response.data
        var newdata = JSON(data: dataExample!)
        self.items = newdata
    }
    return self.items
}
```

But the return statement still errors as if self.items in nil.

Comment: so your `getItemsTwo` is run asynchronously and hasn't returned when you call `var items = self.viewModel.items` is that correctly understood?

Comment: @pbodsk yea that's the issue, can I make it not asynch?

Comment: it depends what it does :) but another way to go could be to add a callback method as a parameter to your `getItemsTwo` method. That method could then include the items as a parameter, and you could then add your `for loop` in the callback. (sorry, it's a bit hard to explain here in the comments, hope I'm making sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could expand your `getItemsTwo` method to take a callback closure, something like:

```
func getItemsTwo(user: MYUser, callback: (items: [JSON])-> Void)
```

Meaning that you have a parameter called `callback` which is a closure function that returns `Void` and takes an array of `JSON` items as an input parameter.

Once you have added `newdata` to `self.items` you could call your callback closure like so:

```
func getItemsTwo(user: MYUser, callback: (items: [JSON])-> Void) {
    let user_id = user.getUserId()
    let url = String(format:"users/%@/items", user_id)
    self.get(url).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
        let dataExample = response.data
        var newdata = JSON(data: dataExample!)
        self.items = new data

        //Items are now populated, call callback
        callback(items: self.items)
    }
}
```

And then, in your `ItemsViewController` you could say:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.viewModel.getItemsTwo(self.viewModel.getCurrentUser()) { items in
        for item in items {
            print(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that if you add a closure as the last parameter you can use a so called "Trailing Closure" and place it "outside" or "after" your function as described [in this chapter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) of "The Swift Programming Language".

Hope that helps you (I haven't checked in a compiler so you might get some errors, but then well look at them OK :)).